# Trying to fix button or sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I created a similar question but has too confused, hope to get some help now giving this shortcode.
I've tried to change all this code from another answer here at StackOverflow. I have able to make the button works but It just removed posts, not from user_id.

**Trying to create a button to remove the post.**

Select:

```
$sth = $db->prepare("
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        users, profile_post 
    WHERE 
        profile_post.user_id = users.user_id AND
        users.user_id = :id
    ORDER BY `profile_post`.`dateupload` DESC
");
```

Form:

```
                echo '<form name="delete" action="" method="post"><button><i class="fa fa-trash"><input type="hidden" name="name" value="' . $row["post"] .'"></i></button></form>';
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
                $postid1 = $row["post"];
                $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM `profile_post` WHERE `profile_post`.`post` = $postid1 ");
                echo("Sucess.");
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: what is $postid in the PHP code? it was not declared

Comment: Also in the Form section you used nested echo? did you mean: echo '<form name="delete" action="" method="post"><button><i class="fa fa-trash"><input type="hidden" name="name" value="' . $row["postid"] .'"></i></button></form>';

Comment: @AmirMB thank you. Maybe what I need now is to call $postid1 =  [BUTTON HIDDEN VALUE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are preparing the query (in the wrong way, because of 2 reasons: `$db` is undeclared and also the query is incorrect), but you have never bound your parameters and executed it:

```
$db = new mysqli($HOST,$USER,$PASS,$DATABASE); // these variables should be defined based on the database credentials
$stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM `profile_post` WHERE `profile_post`.`post` = ?;");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $postid1);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I made with your code, it's working but it's removing a post not from the current post clicking button.

Comment: @AndréSantos when you are creating the button, which post id you are using? it is the same

Comment: $postid = $row["post"];

<input type="hidden" name="delete" value="' . $row["post"] .'"></i></button>
("i", $postid1);

Comment: @AndréSantos I saw this line, but I don't know how you are using the response of your select, please edit the post and show all of your code.

Comment: @AndréSantos you did not declared $postid1 in your code, it should be declared as: $postid1 = $_POST["delete"]